# Why do microsoft define type separately?

Tags: c#

This may be a stupid question but I which I could really get some insight in this thing.
I'm trying to make some projects and to do this effeciently I try to study every day to learn new things.

I often take examples on github to study from but I've seen this pointless things which I really don't understand.
I have seen a function like this

```
public void SomeNewFunction(object value, Type type)
{
VerifyValueAndType(value, type);
//do something
}

private  void VerifyValueAndType(object value, Type type)
{
      if (type == null)
      {
            if (value != null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
            }
       }
       else if (value != null)
       {
            if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                //throw another error
             }
        }
   }
```

Now what I don't understand is why they ask you to give the object type separately and not use the "value.getType()"?
especially when they eventually use the "value.getType()" anyway to compare the types?

I been thinking it could be because of performence but then again, if they just use the getType() immediatly then they wouldn't have to verify.

Can someone explain the use of this?

Comment: the method is comparing a object and a given type. It would be pointless to check if the type of the object is equal to the type of the object. So you need a seperate argument which is the type you want to compare. For example `VerifyValueAndType(int, double)` would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the purpose, but, say you are building a dependency container, for example. you want to register some implementation to an interface, so you can do

```
Register(myServiceImplementation, typeof(IMyService));
```

This allows you to be very explicit about what is being registered. Using `GetType` would yield the type of the implementation, and even if you used reflection to get the whole type/interface tree, it would be less specific.

That said, a better pattern for this kind of thing would be

```
void Register<TInterface>(TInterface implementation);
```

This could be called like so:

```
Register<IMyService>(myServiceImplementation);
```

And would be a bit more type-safe, the validation could be skipped entirely since the error would already have occurred at compile-time.

Comment: well yeah, in the project which I found this example in I see both options. I understand the generic option but I had my doubts about the other one but now with the example you give on the interface ..., I start to see why you would use typeof(IInterface) rather then getType() which will return a class or struct.